# REG file to modify Windows 10 Visual Effects?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, visual-effects

I am trying to figure out how to change Visual Effects in an automated fashion (i.e. batch files, REG files) so it does not need to be manually changed. I'm stuck on Visual Effects right now. I am trying to create a REG file that will put the system in this state:

[image]

Actually I might also check "Show window contents while dragging" but that's about it. I only care strongly about leaving smooth fonts on.

I looked online and found a number of things mostly written for Windows XP and Windows 7. I took bits and pieces as I could to put this together:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects]
;0 = Let Windows choose what’s best for my computer
;1 = Adjust for best appearance
;2 = Adjust for best performance
;3 = Custom
"VisualFXSetting"=dword:00000003

; Do not Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]
"MinAnimate"="0"

; Show window contents while dragging
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"DragFullWindows"=1

; Smooth Edges of Screen Fonts
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"FontSmoothing"="2"

; Do not use drop shadows for icon labels on the desktop
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"ListviewShadow"=0

; Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing
[HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]
"MinAnimate"="1"
```

Obviously, that's nowhere near close to modifying all of the options, but I wanted to at least test what I had. To test this, I checked "Adjust for best appearance" and then ran that REG file to see what would get unchecked. This is what happened:

[image]

I accidentally had the max/min setting twice, but reversed the second time. Oddly enough, even running that, that is the only setting that changed. So I'll leave in the 1 line that worked, but otherwise it looks like I've hit a wall, even with just the few settings I thought would work (and I need to modify ALL of them). Does anyone know what registry keys must be changed for Windows 10?

Comment: Those settings are saved in one registry value [UserPreferenceMask](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957204.aspx) in ` HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop`.

Comment: @Biswa I see, it's just one registry entry. Not easy to work with. Looking at that MSFT link, I don't see all the options in the dialog on the page. How do I set the rest?

Comment: You mentioned those rest registry settings.

Answer (score 8):

Use this if you want to disable everything. Delete lines based on what you want to achieve.
Some settings will appear only after you restart the computer.

I like to keep at least the translucent rectangle, drop shadows for icons on desktop, show window contents when dragging and smoothing the edges of screen fonts.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00


;Apply the following registry values to disable the settings


;This is a must - set appearance options to "custom"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects]
"VisualFXSetting"=dword:3


;This disables the following 8 settings:
;Animate controls and elements inside windows
;Fade or slide menus into view
;Fade or slide ToolTips into view
;Fade out menu items after clicking
;Show shadows under mouse pointer
;Show shadows under windows
;Slide open combo boxes
;Smooth-scroll list boxes
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"UserPreferencesMask"=hex(2):90,12,03,80,10,00,00,00


;Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]
"MinAnimate"="0"


;Animations in the taskbar
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"TaskbarAnimations"=dword:0


;Enable Peek
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM]
"EnableAeroPeek"=dword:0


;Save taskbar thumbnail previews
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM]
"AlwaysHibernateThumbnails"=dword:0


;Show thumbnails instead of icons
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"IconsOnly"=dword:1


;Show translucent selection rectangle
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"ListviewAlphaSelect"=dword:0


;Show window contents while dragging
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"DragFullWindows"="0"


;Smooth edges of screen fonts
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"FontSmoothing"="0"


;Use drop shadows for icon labels on the desktop
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"ListviewShadow"=dword:0

; end
```

This was tested on Windows 10 1809.

Comment: I guess some settings are missing (Animate controls and elements inside windows; Slide open combo boxes), can you update or someone edit this answer?

Comment: There is a setting that enables/disables 8 different settings (including those you have mentioned). I haven't found another way to do it, but nothing is missing.

Comment: The main issue for me is when importing this file, the actual registry entries change, so it is importing but the live configuration doesnt fully change.  So I then rebooted to see if that was the reason.

The following dont change on reg import from the current setting.

Fade settings
Font smoothing
Slide open scroll list boxes.

Might be more as I skipped some to match the default.

If I manually change, it of course works, and in addition I confirm the registry matches as well.

I think the registry you supplied is right, but there is a missing piece of the jigsaw.

Comment: Did you change the first option that is provided in the above script (VisualFXSetting)? That is necessary in order for other changes to work.

Comment: For "Smooth edges of screen fonts", it should be:  "FontSmoothing"="0" to Disable. And "FontSmoothing"="2" to Enable (default) The rest looks good, just tested it, though my settings vary slightly

Comment: A tip for people using this but with their own modifications:  "UserPreferencesMask" is a bit human-unfriendly, so the way I do it is make all the changes in Performance Options by hand, then export the registry and copy-paste UserPreferencesMask to the above reg file. Thanks @GChuf very helpful post!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.
Rough but works without problems.
You uncheck all the boxes with this key "VisualFXSetting"=dword:00000002 and select your parameters with other keys.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects]
    ;0 = Let Windows choose what’s best for my computer
    ;1 = Adjust for best appearance
    ;2 = Adjust for best performance
    ;3 = Custom
    "VisualFXSetting"=dword:00000002
    
    ; Do not Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing
    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]
    "MinAnimate"="0"
    
    ; Show window contents while dragging
    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
    "DragFullWindows"=1
    
    ; Smooth Edges of Screen Fonts
    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
    "FontSmoothing"="2"
    
    ; Do not use drop shadows for icon labels on the desktop
    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
    "ListviewShadow"=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of batch commands that can be run in a command prompt administrator window or saved as a batch file:

```
Echo Windows Explorer Tweaks: Hidden Files,Expand to Current
Echo Change Visual Effects Settings for Best Performance and best looking
:: Change your Visual Effects Settings: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6377-change-visual-effects-settings-windows-10-a.html
:: 0 = Let Windows choose what’s best for my computer
:: 1 = Adjust for best appearance
:: 2 = Adjust for best performance
:: 3 = Custom ;This disables the following 8 settings:Animate controls and elements inside windows;Fade or slide menus into view;Fade or slide ToolTips into view;Fade out menu items after clicking;Show shadows under mouse pointer;Show shadows under windows;Slide open combo boxes;Smooth-scroll list boxes
Reg Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects" /v "VisualFXSetting" /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
Reg Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects" /v "VisualFXSetting" /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f
Reg Add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v "UserPreferencesMask" /t REG_BINARY /d "90 32 07 80 10 00 00 00" /f
:: Open File Explorer to: This PC
Reg Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "LaunchTo" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
:: Show hidden files, folders, and drives
Reg Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "Hidden" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
:: Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)
Reg Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "ShowSuperHidden" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
Reg Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "HideIcons" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
:: Hide extensions for known file types
Reg Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "HideFileExt" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
:: Navigation pane: Expand to open folder
Reg Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "NavPaneExpandToCurrentFolder" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
:: Navigation pane: Show all folders
Reg Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "NavPaneShowAllFolders" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
:: Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing
Reg Add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics" /v "MinAnimate" /d 0 /f
:: Animations in the taskbar
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "TaskbarAnimations" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
:: Enable Peek
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM" /v "EnableAeroPeek" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
:: Save taskbar thumbnail previews
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM" /v "AlwaysHibernateThumbnails" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
:: Show translucent selection rectangle
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "ListviewAlphaSelect" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
:: Show thumbnails instead of icons
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "IconsOnly" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
:: Show window contents while dragging
Reg Add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v "DragFullWindows" /d 0 /f
:: Smooth edges of screen fonts
Reg Add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v "FontSmoothing" /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
:: Use drop shadows for icon labels on the desktop
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "ListviewShadow" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Answer (score -1):

This page [How to Change Visual Effects Settings in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6377-change-visual-effects-settings-windows-10-a.html) says the folowing:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\UserPreferencesMask**

```
Binary sets (3)
1001ABC0 00D1EF10 00000G11

0=off and 1=on

Visual Effects and their assigned letters
(A) Smooth-scroll list boxes
(B) Slide open combo boxes
(C) Fade or slide menus into view
(D) Show shadows under mouse pointer
(E) Fade or slide ToolTips into view
(F) Fade out menu items after clicking
(G) Show shadows under windows

For example, to turn them all off, I would change all letters in the binary sets to 0 (number zero) like below.

10010000 00010010 00000011

For example, to turn only the C visual effect on, I would change the letters in the binary sets like below.

10010010 00010010 00000011
```

Answer (score -3):

Solution is :

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"UserPreferencesMask"=hex(3):90,12,03,80,10,02,00,00
"DragFullWindows"="0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]
"MinAnimate"="0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"ShellState"=hex(3):24,00,00,00,3E,28,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,01,00,00,00,13,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,72,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"IconsOnly"=dword:00000001
"ListviewAlphaSelect"=dword:00000000
"ListviewShadow"=dword:00000000
"TaskbarAnimations"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects]
"VisualFXSetting"=dword:00000003

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM]
"AlwaysHibernateThumbnails"=dword:00000000
"EnableAeroPeek"=dword:00000000
```

This setting  - ONLY Smooth edges of screen fonts ACTIVE (must restart PC)

Tested to Windows 10 1803 build 17134.1

Comment: This seems to be a [Try This!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice) answer. Can you please improve it a little and explain why you want the asker to try that and what you changed. Thanks